# python3-invalid syntax on a line that do not exist

Tags: python, regex, zip

python3-invalid syntax error

File "6_1.py", line 8

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

But there is no line 8. So what is the problem.

```
import zipfile,re
with ZipFile('../../下载/channel.zip') as myzip:
    nothing = '90052'
    rex = re.compile(r'\d+')
    while True:
        print(myzip.getinfo(nothing+'txt'))
        nothing = re.findall(rex, myzip.open(nothing+'txt')[0]
```

Comment: Please, next time post the *full* traceback, not just the last line. For *full* traceback I mean everything between the line that starts with `Traceback` to the line you posted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, but Python thinks there should be because line 7 is not complete:

```
nothing = re.findall(rex, myzip.open(nothing+'txt')[0]        
#              open 1 -------- open 2 ----- close 2 - ^ where is close 1?
```

There is a closing `)` missing at the end.